# Why do TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC") and TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(x => x.Id == "UTC") give different results?

Tags: c#

I would expect

```
TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(x => x.Id == anId)
```

to always give the same result as

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(anId)
```

where anId is the same ID string in both cases. However, this is not the case as demonstrated by the following code example.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Utc
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Outputs (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time
            Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(x => x.Id == "UTC").DisplayName);

            // Outputs UTC
            Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC").DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(x => x.Id == "UTC").Id).DisplayName);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Note that this result was generated with C# version 4.7.2, and gave the same result in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You are two different results because as per the `TimeZoneInfo.cs` implementation of [GetSystemTimeZones()](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs#L921) will try to lookup into `Registry.LocalMachine` and collect timezones data.

In case of [FindSystemTimeZoneById](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs#L1944) it has condition like below. If it doesn't match then it will retrieve from `Registry.LocalMachine`.

```
if (String.Compare(id, c_utcId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) {
    return TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,1949) for `FindSystemTimeZoneById`:

```
// Special case for Utc as it will not exist in the dictionary with the rest
// of the system time zones.  There is no need to do this check for Local.Id
// since Local is a real time zone that exists in the dictionary cache
if (String.Compare(id, c_utcId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) {
    return TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
}
```

The dictionary it's referring to is populated from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`, and is what `GetSystemTimeZones` returns.

However, I don't believe the comment and logic are correct, because my Windows 10 build 1803 machine has a "UTC" entry at the aforementioned registry path (presumably your computer has the same). It looks like this may have been true in earlier versions of Windows, but perhaps not anymore - [have filed a bug in the corefx repo to get clarity](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37173).

Answer (score 0):

This code was written long ago and during that time the assumption is Utc was not enumerated on the machine and will not be stored in the local dictionary. I agree this is not the case now. Although I am not seeing this can cause a real problem here as both Utc created object will behave correctly, but I think it would be better to fix that and ensure we use one Utc object.

@Ian Kemp, thanks for opening the issue in corefx repo. We'll take care with the issue in the future releases of .NET Core.